# How to test ECS autoscaling properly?

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-auto-scaling

I have a ECS service that I have set up auto-scaling for. It is a service that has 2 Fargate tasks. The problem is the Docker containers' CPU utilization is usually very low, generally around 0.1%. I would like to test my auto-scaling set up, especially auto-scaling down which should happen when CPU utilization drops below a threshold. What is the best approach to test it?

Answer (score 0):

If your app exposes an HTTP API, you could use load testers such as [hey](https://github.com/rakyll/hey) or [ab](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) to generate load and hence trigger scaling.

Answer (score -1):

I've been also thought about that before, then I was adjusting the threshold from 50% to 0.1% to trigger the auto-scaling, as well as adjusted the scale-in threshold.